# value not retained in text box in parent window when passed from child window

Tags: jsf, jstl, jboss7.x

I am trying to populate a value in the textbox in my parent window.There is a button in my child window on click of which the child window should close and it should assign value to the text box in the parent window as well.I am using JSF 1.1 along with Jboss 7.x .
Below are the code snippets written in child and parent window :

**Child Window Code :**

```
<script>
    function post_value(x) {
    document.getElementById("createData:setId").value = x;
    return true;
}
</script>
```

**Parent Window Code :**

```
<td align="left" width="20%"><h:inputText id="setId"
value="#{createData.claimDataVo.Id}"
readonly="#{facesContext.renderResponse}" size="20"                                                                  
maxlength="20" styleClass="inputText_ReadOnly" label="Assign Data">                                                               
</h:inputText></td>
```

Comment: There is nothing visible in your code that shows how it is (possibly) passed on from parent window to child window, so it is impossible to help in this regards